# File Transfer One Org to another Org using Dataloader.io

Tags: salesforce-id, dataloader.io

I have tried to Import File/Attachment one sandbox to another sandbox using Dataloader.io. and we have follow this https://dataloader.io/dealing-attachments steps.

but I can't and got the "The attachment body has an incorrect type. Expected byte[] or InputStream" error.
[image]

Have anyone has great solution to overcome this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got "byte[] or InputStream" error in DataLoader.IO due to your file is not getting by them.

We need to follow their steps(https://dataloader.io/dealing-attachments) but you need to take care of below points.

1) .zip file contains only files. (No any subfolder in it)

2) .csv file contains "File Name" and "Body" as a full file name with extension.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same value for the "File Name" and "Body" columns (the name of the file) in my csv file and that worked. Please see below:
[image: csv file to import attachments via dataloader.io]